# How do I generate App Clip codes via Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code, apple-appclips

I know I can [generate an App Clip code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/creating_app_clip_codes) using the generator or App Store Connect. What I'd like to build is a feature similar to Venmo's where a user can scan a QR code (App Clip code in this case) in the app and send money.

Therefore, I need the ability to dynamically generate these codes via Swift rather than the command line tool.

Is there a way to generate these App Clip codes via Swift?

I know I can do the exact same thing with QR codes, but I like the visual look of the App Clip code.

Comment: AFAIK the spec for App Clip codes is not public. Would it be good enough to request an APC from a macOS server running the CLI tool?